# Count the number of list elements that does not include certain strings

Tags: python

I have a very large text file containing 900000 lines. I have to count the lines which do not have 'year1995' and 'year1996' in the line. I did as follows:

```
fname = r"data.txt"
with open(fname,'r') as fi:
    lines = fi.read().splitlines()
    print len(lines)
    test = [l for l in lines if 'year1995' or 'year1996' not in l]
    print len(test)
```

BUT my code is not producing expected result.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not just doing "egrep -v "year1995|year1996" data.txt" ? And to count, just add "| wc -l" at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have there will put every single line in `test`. This is because the first `if` statement will always evaluate to `True` because non-empty strings are truthy. Change the test within the comprehension:

```
[l for l in lines if not ('year1995' in l or 'year1996' in l)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pointless creating a list to throw it away, just use sum:

```
with open(fname,'r') as fi:
       print sum(not any(x in line for x in ('year1995','year1996' ) ) for line in fi)
```

`lines = fi.read().splitlines()` is also not needed, just iterate over the file object which will be each line.

Comment: Nicer , indeed! An probably more memory efficient

Comment: @Apero, def more efficient, unless the OP needs the lists which they don't seem to, creating two lists is pointless

Comment: But I still wouldn't use python for this, as mentioned in my comment to the question itself. Unless the OP wants do process the filtered out lines in the code, after this section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `if` condition to :

```
if not 'year1995' in l or not 'year1996' in l
```

or

```
if not ('year1995' in l or 'year1996' in l)
```

Note : **you need to put a condition after `not` operation** !